# Magento: Including a file in Easytabs template file

Tags: magento, plugins

I want to customise the Magento Easytabs plugin. I want to include n `.phtml` file in the `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/easytabs/tabs.phtml` file of Magento Easytabs plugin.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after next line

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
```

Please add next line of code

```
<block type="core/template" name="my_product_finder" as="my_product_finder" template="templatedir/productfinder.phtml"/>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to write my code, which is little different than what you suggested depending on my requirement.